# How to read reactions from a DM channel on discord using discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

While programming a discord bot, I realized that I needed to read reactions that the bot dmed to different users.

Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    channel = reaction.message.channel
    await channel.send('{} has added {} to the message: {}'.format(user.name, reaction.emoji, reaction.message.content))
```

This reads a message from basically any channel that the bot is in (e.g. in guilds), as opposed to just DM channels. Is there a fix for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can check if the message is in a guild or not, and then base your logic off that

Comment: I have already tried this approach, it's just that whenever I put it into a conditional, it reads that DMChannel has no attribute guild, which makes sense, and thus rules out this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to this realization just before so I'll add it as an answer.
You can just use `isinstance` to check the channel type as dpy has different internal class's for all channels.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    if not isinstance(reaction.message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        # Not a dm
        return

    print("Hey this should be a dm")
```

That code will only ever run in dms.
Alternately, you could remove the `not` and put your dm code within the `if` statement